# Impossibility of lossless matched 3-port combiner

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, acoustics

It is a well-known result of scattering matrix theory (acoustic or EM) that a lossless 3-port cannot be matched. In other words, one cannot combine (sum) two *arbitrary* coherent waves arriving at two separate ports into a lossless summing junction without reflection no matter how the 3rd port is terminated. The result follows trivially from the fact that a scattering matrix of a lossless junction is unitary. The word *arbitrary* describing the waves is needed for any particular pair of amplitudes and phases can always combined without reflection but when once those are changed we get imperfect summing.

Such a basic result should be explicable by some simple and intuitive physical argument without resorting to scattering matrices and their unitarity. Can somebody give an intuitive argument without resorting to reciprocity by which feeding the 3rd port leads to a fixed amplitude/phase relationship in the other two thereby excluding arbitrary amplitudes/phases?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have such a device. You have ports $A$, $B$, and $C$. Suppose $A$ and $B$ add to give $C$.

Now put a coherent wave of amplitude $1$ and phase $0$ on both of $A$ and $B$. You would expect a coherent wave of amplitude $2$ and phase $0$ on port $C$.

Now instead put a coherent wave of amplitude $2$ and phase $0$ on $A$ and put nothing on port $B$. You would again expect a coherent wave of amplitude $2$ and phase $0$ on $C$.

Now, reverse the system. Put a coherent wave of amplitude $2$ and phase $0$ on $C$. What do you expect to get on $A$ and $B$? Does it split evenly reversing into the first situation above or does all of the power go out one port? Or is it an unequal split? What fraction would it be?

This is the essential idea of unitarity. Unitary implies time reversible. Input states have a deterministic 1:1 mapping with output states meaning that given any output state you can figure out what input states it "came from". The lossless summing junction breaks this 1:1 mapping so cannot exist.

Comment: Your argument assumes that ports A and B are isolated, this need not be the case unless the junction is also nonreciprocal, ie.,  the S matrix is asymmetrical. Also, I explicitly asked for an argument that is not based on the reversal starting from port C. A 3-port junction can have unequal amplitude splits and thus unequal amplitude sums. Although your 1:1 mapping argument is interesting I am looking for an reasoning that uses only "forward" waves, if there is one. Note too that it is not obvious at all that any termination (i.e., mismatched and/or complex load) will still give reflections.

Comment: Not sure. I'll need to learn more before I can give an answer. But I'll add that perhaps it may be beneficial to approach the problem from the point of view that general multiport networks can't be matched and networks which *can* be matched are in fact the "unique" ones. That is, instead of asking why can't lossless 3 port networks be matched, instead ask why CAN lossless two port networks be matched.

Comment: I think the word "match" here is confusing and ambiguous although standard. It is used to set a load at the passive end whose impedance is equal to the wave impedance of the transmission line connecting to a port of the junction so that port is terminated properly. Another sense regards the junction itself being called matched when the diagonal elements of its scattering matrix  are all zero, these do not depend on the loads but they "match" the transmission lines so that the n-junction acts as a summer when driven from n-1 ports into the nth without reflection from the junction in any port.

Answer (score -1):

For about 50 years RF engineers have been combining and splitting wave energy using device's like:  3dB hybrids, directional couplers, Lang couplers and Wilkinson power dividers/ combiners. Signals must be frequency and phase coherent to maximize the combining effect.

Comment: The question asked for an intuitive explanation as to why a lossless 3-port cannot be "matched" and not for a list of 4-ports that have a dissipating matching resistor inside them.

Comment: @hyportnex..The Wilkinson divider/combiner is a 3 port lossless device. all the devices I mentioned have resistors in them but do not dissipate for frequency and phase coherent signals. all these devices can be matched. I'm not sure what you point is.

Comment: A Wilkinson divider is a lossy 3-port where the matching resistor is built-in the circuit, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson_power_divider ; if you do not have an internal matching resistor you can only combine in-phase equal amplitude waves without reflection. The conventional branch-line hybrids or directional couplers, say a Lange, Bethe, Levy, etc., coupler are 4-port devices that to be matched have a an external or sometimes built-in resistors.

Comment: @hyportnex.. Your local UHF TV transmitter on a hill near you uses thousands of transistor amplifier's with very low loss (bit of copper and dielectric loss, 0.5 dB). the phase and frequency signals are split and recombined  after the amps in multiple stages to output 50 or 100 kilowatts. the last stage transistors may only output 50 watts each, with only 10 or 15 dB gain. A klystron could probably do all of this in one shot but it's only vacuum tube.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. A "matched" n-port has scattering matrix such that the diagonal elements $S_{ii}=0$ ($i=1,2,..n$), consequently  there would be no reflection if any of its ports is individually excited. Unfortunately, one cannot have "matched" and "lossless" and "reciprocal" 3-port for which $S_{ik}=S_{ki}$ ($k\ne i$), my question is why so? The math is simple but I am looking for an intuitive explanation why this is so.

Comment: @hyportnex.. I'm still confused, you say a lossless 3 port can't be matched? A Wilkinson is a lossless 3 port that can be matched. but you have now added reciprocal into the problem? I would have to think about this for a bit.  All devices so far use transmission lines in some way and don't possess natural symmetry but cavity devices can be more symmetrical. consider a Luneberg Lens for awhile could it fit the bill? My best guess at a simple intuitive approach is symmetry all ports have equal standing and are interchangeable, any port can be an input or an output. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @hyportnex...The only power dissipated in the terminations in any of these devices is return loss due to inevitable small mismatches, it is best to dissipate it to prevent the return loss from causing signal distortion in TV signals for example, it will appear as ghosting in analogue signals. And loss of signal to noise ratio in digital  signals .You can see that I am a practitioner and you are a theoretician and or mathematician  It is therefore difficult to communicate sometimes.

Comment: One more time: a Wilkinson divider is NOT lossless because it has a resistor inside that will DISSIPATE $1/2$ of the incident power if driven by a source on its port "2" (ports numbered 1,2,3, so that "2" and "3" are symmetrical relative to "1"). If you remove the resistor (usually 70$\Omega$ in a 50$\Omega$ system) then the power that would have been absorbed will be reflected, in other words, the Wilkinson divider is *not* a "matched" network even if all its terminations are matched properly.

Comment: But note that an ideal circulator while not reciprocal is lossless and is fully matched for $S_{11}=S_{22}=S_{33}=0$, so you can drive it from any of its ports and get no reflections.

Comment: @hyportnex....I'm sorry but I must disagree. the resistor is always 100 ohms the quarter wave lines are 70.7 ohms the resistors only dissipate return loss if all ports are not 50 ohms or the two signals to be combined or split are not identical.

Comment: You are right, it is 100$\Omega$ but we are arguing over the definition of what is "matched". To avoid that sterile argument my question please explain why we cannot have $S_{ii}=0$ ($i=1,2,3$) for a lossless reciprocal 3-port without going through the unitarity analysis, ie., intuitively?

Comment: @hyportnex.. The reciprocal troubles me I can't quite come to grips with explaining it or I simply don't know.  I did mention the Luneberg lens, are you familiar with them? they may be reciprocal, they certainly have no nasty resistors in them I anticipated using  them 25 years ago as simultaneous multiple inderpendant beam antennas but settled for Butler matrices instead, google them if you are not familiar with them I'm almost certain they are used in the 5G network, they are very interesting. All military aircraft use them.

Comment: yes, I am quite familiar with both Mr. LunebUrg (U not e) and Mr. Butler; their lenses while being lossless are also reciprocal, but note that Luneburg has infinite (>3) number of ports and Butler has $2^n, n\ge 2$ (also more than 3) ports. As much as I love both lenses I do not see their relevance to my question.

Comment: @hyportnex...Why would you bother correcting my spelling, more importantly, as far as I'm aware there is no reason why a LunebUrg Lens can't have three ports or even two?  I still think your hung up on loss by by the 100 Ohm resistor in the the Wilkinson. And also the loss in the terminated port in 90 deg hybrid or a directional coupler.

Comment: Used as transmitter *every* point on the surface of a Luneburg lens is potential focal point (input port) collimating into the opposite radial *direction*, the output port. The corresponding question would be is it conceivable to have two such focal points along with a third direction so that *any* (arbitrary phase/amplitude) coherent sum could appear on it as collimated output. And the answer is no, you cannot have that as it follows from the unitarity and reciprocity of the scattering matrix. I was asking for an intuitive explanation that an HR manager on the 2nd floor could understand.

Comment: @hyportnex..."an intuitive explanation that an HR manager on the 2nd floor could understand." Yikes, that's a big ask, My heart goes out to you.   20 years in retirement has spoilt me.  I'm interested in your question still, I'm a masochist I guess? The mod's or bot's are not happy with long discussions, but you might want to go to chat to discuss the actual application, If it is a mathematical curiosity I might have to "tap out".  I could give a totally non mathematical qualitative description of a directional coupler or 3 dB 90 deg hybrid to a lay person, probably not to a manager though?