# Why can't you make a perfectly symmetric beam splitter in practice?

Tags: waves

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_splitter#Classical_lossless_beam_splitter), conservation of energy forces a beam splitter with two input beams to have a unitary beam-splitter transfer matrix.

If I am correct, this implies that the beam splitter can not be symmetric.
Here with `symmetric', I mean that both input beams would be equally divided between the two output beams. The matrix would then consist of four elements $\frac12\sqrt{2}$, and that is not a unitary matrix.

I understand that such a `symmetric beam-splitter' would violate conservation of energy. However, I don't see why you can't make this in practice. After all, you only need a symmetric mirror which lets half of the light pass through it. So what happens in practice when you try to make a symmetric beam-splitter?

Comment: similar question, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/487465/impossibility-of-lossless-matched-3-port-combiner

Comment: This is not exactly the same as the "3-port" item iin @hyportnex link.   If you have a simple, say partially silvered 50% beamsplitter,  then all input/output beams split and combine  with perfect symmetry.  Maybe you are messing with the wrong transfer matrix?

Comment: @Carl Witthoft, if what you say is true then that beamsplitter would not satisfy conservation of energy, right? Because, if you use an imput beam of amplitude 2 and phase 0, and an imput beam of amplitude 1 and phase 0, then the output energy (sum of squares of amplitudes) would be different from the input energy (17)

Comment: @Riemann you can't do energy that way even with two perfectly collimated beams of matching wavelength.  As you rightly suppose, the energy has to go "somewhere" ; but the actual interference (like fringes from an aperture) only occurs when the waves collapse on an imaging surface.   Maybe you're forgetting about phase shift differences on transmission vs. reflection?

Comment: what's wrong with having relative phases, which do not enter in the transmittivity or reflectivity?